# incompatible class error in selenium appium

Tags: selenium, appium

This is my main class. i tried to automate a simple test case of launching a browser and hitting on search button on google.com

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DesiredCapabilities capabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilites.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto X Style");
    capabilites.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilites.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");

    capabilites.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    capabilites.setCapability("appActivity", "org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity");

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilites);

    driver.findElementById("com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text").click();
}
```

I got the following error pls help

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at launchApp.LaunchApp1.main(LaunchApp1.java:27)
```